# "Warning: pip, pip3, and pip3.10 scripts are at '/usr/local/python/3.10.8/bin' not on PATH. Add to PATH or use --no-warn-script-location?"

Tags: python, installation, pip

On VS Code, I tried to use pip to install the newest version of Python using the command `$ pip install python 3.12.1` (I didn't know if VS code repos do this automatically or manually, and trying it with pip seemed to be a good option (if there's a way to do it, please tell me)).

When I did, it said:

> [notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.3.1 -> 23.3.2

Of course, I updated it, and then it showed me this:

> WARNING: The scripts pip, pip3 and pip3.10 are installed in
> '/usr/local/python/3.10.8/bin' which is not on PATH.   Consider adding
> this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use
> --no-warn-script-location.

My questions:

1. What exactly is it telling me?
2. What will happen if I don't do anything?
3. Is it worth fixing, and is it an actual problem (similar to #2)?
4. What is the difference between adding it to PATH or using a --no-warn-script-location?
5. What should I do?

Comment: Add '/usr/local/python/3.10.8/bin' to the path is the best option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What exactly is it telling me?

That any script under `/usr/local/python/3.10.8/bin` is not accessible like regular commands like `ls` or `cd`. `which <script>` command will not find them. Typing a few characters of script name and hitting tab twice will give no good results.

> What will happen if I don't do anything?

Full path to the script will be needed to run them

> Is it worth fixing, and is it an actual problem (similar to #2)?

I believe it is since it a simple fix but it depends on specific needs. Not an actual problem if you know what to do if an script is not found. It's a convenience problem probably.

> What is the difference between adding it to PATH or using a --no-warn-script-location?

Using `--no-warn-script-location` means script location path is not important to you (because you know what you are doing?). Fixing PATH explained above.

> What should I do?

Fix the PATH (recommended) or not. Depends on one's needs.